# how to specify the initial path for Ember application?

Tags: ember.js, window.location, address-bar

I want to specify `/licenses/all` as the default path for my emberjs application. When I do not specify any path in `ApplicationController` of `ApplicationRotue`, the path remains something like `http://localhost:8080/` and nothing loads. But if I specify `transitionToRoute(all-licenses)` in `ApplicationRoute`, the path gets reset to the one specified, everytime I refresh the page (and hence refresh the application). I want the path to remain the same on refresh, but also the application should be redirected to the default path if root path is selected (`/`). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you hit the root of your app (`/`) it hits the application route, but since you've only hit the `/` it will also hit the default route for the root of your site, the `IndexRoute`.  That makes it a good candidate for hooking up the redirect.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    this.transitionTo('licenses.all'):
  }
});
```